# How to draw a figure while posting a question in stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, images

I want to draw a figure to illustrate a question while posting it on math.stackexchange. I don't know how to do so?

In particular I want to draw a frustum and unable to do so. Can I do it?? If so how??

Comment: Sometimes, I use LaTeXiT. Or you can look in Google images for something that looks like your purpose and add some comment to adapt it.

Comment: what if I want to add my own figure??

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9632/creating-diagrams (and also the links mentioned there in comments).

Comment: I'm suggesting closing as duplicate so this question is clearly/obviously linked to the question @Martin mentioned. (for future searches)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would make a figure in Paint, Gimp or something similar, and then upload it using the available button here:

[image]